# How Do I convert a String into CSV File using CSVWriter

Tags: java

I have a String that looks like this:

```
Year;Make;Model;Params
1997;Ford;E350;[2.35, 1.11]
2000;Mercury;Cougar;[2.38 3.23]
```

I wonder how can I convert this into a CSV file using semi-colon as the delimiter and not comma?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I've tried using BufferedWriter but I don't know how to let the writer accept semicolon and create columns based on ";" and not the comma... I have many commas in my data filed and therefore I prefer using ; as the separator instead of comma...

Comment: Please add the relevant code.  Specifically, please be sure to include the code where the input is received (from file or user or wherever) as well as the code where you're generating your output/csv.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the context of this question is about. Just use a String.replace(";",",") call. The code for that is here is pretty simple.

Comment: Is this going to work since I have comma in [2.35, 1.11]  and I want to keep these two number in same field...

Answer (score 0):

Create CSVWriter just with writer as below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException;

String[] arr = {"Year;Make;Model;Params", "1997;Ford;E350;[2.35, 1.11]",
            "2000;Mercury;Cougar;[2.38 3.23]"};

    CSVWriter csvWriter = null;

    try {
        Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("C:\\test.csv"));
        csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer);
        csvWriter.writeNext(arr[0].split(";"));
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            csvWriter.writeNext(arr[i].split(";"));
        }
    } finally {
        if (csvWriter != null)
            csvWriter.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the context of this question is about. Just use a String.replace(";",",") call. The code for that is here is pretty simple.

I just assumed that you were only looking for a means to get started. CSV files have a way to deal with enclosed commas
. You must set them off from a delimiter status by enclosing it between two quotation mark as such '[2.35, 1.11]'. This lets the delimiter logic to disregard  the comma in CSV parsing. It is called escaping the squence. Hopefully the information below will help you.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2028830.aspx?How+to+Escape+Comma+while+exporting+data+to+CSV+file.